# Как к проекту добавить form2?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Каким образом можно добавить к проекту новую форму? У меня есть один проект с одной формой, и по истечении времени должна появляться другая форма... так вот как мне ее в visual studio 2010 добавить к первой форме так, чтобы я  мог её конструировать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Solution Explorer (Обозреватель решений) кликаем правой кнопкой на нужном проекте, выбираем команду Add(Добавить) и выбираем Windows Form...

Answer (score 1):

Когда добавляете Form она будет в соседней вкладке, там можно редактировать. Всплывание привязать к таймеру, команда показа **"show"** на сколько я помню. *(HardMode)* Так же можно создать еще один проект с формой, отредактировать и привязать к нужной.